# How to I completely delete a branch for a specific file in clearcase?

Tags: branch, clearcase

I have a couple files that I want to work with on some branched but not others.  For these files, the clearcase branching looks like this:

```
Dev ---> Dev/speical_branch_1
    ---> Dev/test_branch_1
```

I want to completely obliterate the test branch for both of these files so that the clearcase branching looks like this

```
Dev --> Dev/special_branch_1
```

How do I erase this branch from existence **for only these files**?

This is different from [How to delete a clearcase branch with a single command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48426170/how-to-delete-a-clearcase-branch-with-a-single-command) becasue I want to delete the branch for specific files.  It is also different from [Delete file from ClearCase checked out on another branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5215467/delete-file-from-clearcase-checked-out-on-another-branch) because I do not want to delete the files outright, but only remove certain branches from them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would be using [`cleartool rmver`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_7.1.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_rmver.htm) using a version-extended pathname, or a [version selector](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_7.1.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/version_selector.htm) (for base CC only, not UCM).

The idea is to delete the extended path version of the file for that branch

```
cleartool rmver -force -version \main\Dev\test_branch_1\1 myFile
```

(use / on Unix, \ on Windows)

Or, shorter: delete all versions between 1 and LATEST on the test_branch_1 branch of element myFile

```
cleartool rmver -vrange  \main\Dev\test_branch_1\1  \main\Dev\test_branch_1\LATEST myFile
```

That can be dangerous, especially in ClearCase UCM, where each version can have metadata (attributes) associated to it, which can break objects (like baselines).
[`rmver` is often blocked](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26215182/6309) in that case.

But in base ClearCase, if you have not set anything on those versions, and do not intend to use that branch for that file... that should work.

I mentioned [`cleartool rmbranch -f file@@/main/aBranch`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_rmbranch.htm) 'seen in [Brian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4223401/brian-cowan)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59771589/6309)) as an alternative approach in "[Command to delete branches of Clearcase element with “0” versions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18183902/6309)".

Answer (score 0):

@VonC. That answer is not correct. You CANNOT remove the \0 version on a branch.

If you are removing an entire branch instance from a file, and this is NOT a UCM environment, you would use:

```
cleartool rmbranch myfile@@\main\branch
```

If it is a UCM environment, things get a little more challenging, and it's often best to leave them there and create a new stream.

Comment: As it changed since 2013? I did remove version 0 in https://stackoverflow.com/a/18183902/6309

Comment: It might be only /main/0 that is completely irremovable. But /0 versions are pretty darn important. They are the roots of the various subtrees. I would never explicitly remove a /0 version unless the underlying container was corrupt, then I'd use rmver -data instead. (or let checkvob do it.

Comment: OK, I understand. I try to avoid rmver as much as possible indeed, for version 0 or any version for that matter.